# How to rotate object in a circle in android

Tags: android

I have a circle object and inside of it  there are more small objects that are supposed to turn around with the circle.
Currently the circle spinning but I can not rotate the objects with the large circle.

I would be happy if someone could help

Thank you

rotate of the circle

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <rotate
android:toDegrees="360"
android:startOffset="0"
android:repeatMode="restart"
android:repeatCount="800"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:duration="3500"/>
</set>
```

rotate of the object inside the circle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <rotate

android:toDegrees="360"
android:startOffset="0"
android:repeatMode="restart"
android:repeatCount="800"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:duration="3500"

    />
 </set>
```

and in the code :

```
  Animation animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
  ImageView mimage =(ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.image);
  animRotate= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotateobject);
  mimage.startAnimation(animRotate);
```

Comment: please add your layout or your code to your question.

Comment: mimage?  if you make this some type of view parent and you animate it all objects inside it will also animate.

Comment: the animation  not built together.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
android:pivotY="0%"
android:pivotX="100%"
```

by

```
android:pivotY="50%p"
android:pivotX="50%p"
```

in your children animation. It will set pivot relative to the view's parent.

Comment: I tried it
the small object  moves but they do not move together